# Is there an effective way to test whether a script only uses POSIX features?

Tags: shell, posix

If I wanted to be sure that a script I have written is as portable as possible and only uses [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) features and no, say, [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) features, is there an explicit way to check this?

Obviously, I could try running it in a different shell to my usual shell, but that only confirms that my script is limited to features supported by that shell... features that, themselves, might go beyond [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) mode of [BASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), easily run:

```
bash --posix /PathToYourScript
```

to get in it and run your script there.

It should give you a pretty clear idea of if your Script is [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-
compatible or not.

From what I read, [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash:_Ubuntu,_Debian_and_POSIX_compliance_of_Linux_distributions), which is standard (`sh` is a symbolic link to `dash`) on Ubuntu / Debian and derivatives is a very strict [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell, which may be worth trying, because it's even stricter than [BASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) in [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) mode.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to [Tim Schumacher's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/866114/311264) would be to copy paste the script to [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), only changing the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to `#!/bin/sh`, and carefully studying the output.

This approach may be even better in case you are coding something and you are looking not only for non-compliance with [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), but also for other errors and suggestions. You will be impressed especially, if you use it on daily basis.

---

Of course, you can do:

```
bash --posix /PathToYourScript
```

But from my experience, [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash:_Ubuntu,_Debian_and_POSIX_compliance_of_Linux_distributions), which is standard on Ubuntu / Debian and derivatives (`sh` is a symbolic link to `dash`), is a very strict [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell, and even stricter than [BASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) in [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) mode.